# Kafka-connect docker image built as appuser - how to build it as root?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to build a Kafka-Connect image in Docker:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt wepay/kafka-connect-bigquery:1.6.1
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/connect-transforms:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/landoop-plugins
COPY kafka-connect-redis-1.2.2-2.1.0-all.jar /usr/share/landoop-plugins/
```

but it runs as `appuser`

```
Step 4/4 : RUN id
 ---> Running in d2094f6336a7
uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
```

so if I want for example

`RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/landoop-plugins`

it stops because of root privilages:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/share/landoop-plugins': Permission denied
The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir -p /usr/share/landoop-plugins' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I can add `USER root` at the beginning of Dockerfile:

```
Step 3/15 : RUN id
 ---> Running in 6255e2e7ff81
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

but then  if I ran the container, I am logged as `appuser` which causes problems with permissions:
`[appuser@connect ~]$`.

Actually, in source image
[confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.0.0](https://hub.docker.com/layers/confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect/6.0.0/images/sha256-3d5f%5B%E2%80%A6%5Dc65a91d8095720693d7147667caec1b4a87ed0a340394?context=explore)
there is a layer `USER appuser` so my question is how can I build my image as `root` and then login as `root` and do not use `appuser` user. I've tried and `USER root` does not help.

Is it somehow connected with groups?

```
groups
gignac sudo docker
```

I tried `docker build` and `sudo docker build` as well

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your current `Dockerfile` please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something similar, when I need to create my own plugin to Kafka Connect but I don't exactly do it as root.
Simply I put my jars in a place I have permission to write and just configure the plugins Environment Setting

something like this:

```
FROM    confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.2

ENV     CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH='/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components'

COPY    converter/* /usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/
COPY    format/* /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-storage-common/
```

would this not work?

Comment: `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH` is correct. You don't need `KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

For installing packages and troubleshooting, we would require root user. Using version 5.5.3 does the trick wherein the APPUSER is not created and root is loaded by default.
The version can be verified by

```
http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

which provides the version details.